# Unable to repair booting problem

Tags: boot-repair

I am facing this situation. I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 Since yesterday, I am stuck into Windows. When rebooting, my screen stays black, until it boots into Windows again. Not going into bios or grub. So i cant even start from a bootable USB or disc. Last week i installed grub customizer, and recently I set it up to boot into the last used operating system. Any ideas, while it seems that I can't even format my disk, while i can't change boot order?

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you restart. This will bring up the GRUB menu.

On UEFI systems, <kbd>Esc</kbd> works too.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved